# How to use os.date() to schedule app to turn off?

Tags: timer, coronasdk, schedule

I'm getting a big problem with that. Can someone help?
Thanks.

```
local timer;
function start(e)
  timer = os.date("!*t", os.time() + 60);
  print(timer);
end
someObject:addEventListener("tap", start);

function verifyTimer()
 if(timer == 60)then
  os.exit();
 end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", verifyTimer)
```

Comment: I tried creating timers, but the timers pauses when the device is suspended...

Comment: `local time1 = os.date( "!*t", os.time() + 60000 )`
How am I supposed to reset that thing if the user wishes to cancel the timer he had started?

Comment: `local time1 = os.date( "!*t", os.time() + 60000 )`
How am I supposed to reset that thing if the user wishes to cancel the timer he had started?
I tried verifying the value of time1 by `if(time1)`, but I got nothing...

Comment: can you post your code ...?

Comment: Posted, krs. The variable "timer" seems to have a no-printable value... No value appears on debugger screen.

Answer (score 0):

Apple only permits a few things to run in the background and timers is not one of them.  Your timer will be suspended when the app suspends for whatever reason.  If you want to have something happen in the future, you need to set a local notification event which Corona does support.

I'm pretty sure Google enforces the same thing.

Comment: http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/32705-how-to-use-osdate-to-schedule-app-to-turn-off/